# How to convert a csv data in to a market basket format?

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I have data in following format:

```
TxnId    Items
    1        a
    1        b
    1        c
    2        r 
    2        t
```

where "TxnId" and "Items" are columns. I imported the file in R  and ran following commands:

```
df_fact <- data.frame(lapply(MyData,as.factor))
df_trans <- as(df_fact, 'transactions')
```

when I run apriori command it throws an error.

```
rules = apriori(df_trans, parameter=list(supp=0.95, conf=0.95, target=”rules”))
inspect(rules)
#NULL
inspect(rules[1:5])
Error in inspect(rules[1:5]) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'inspect': Error in slot(x, s)[i] : subscript out of bounds
```

Also let me know in what format R accepts data.

Comment: The result of `inspect(rules)` is `NULL`. Your object is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It should work like this:

```
MyData <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
TxnId    Items
1        a
1        b
1        c
2        a 
2        b
")
library(arules)
df_trans <- as(split(MyData$Items, MyData$TxnId), "transactions")
rules <- apriori(df_trans, parameter=list(supp=0.95, conf=0.95, target="rules"))
inspect(rules)
#   lhs    rhs support confidence lift
# 1 {}  => {a}       1          1    1
# 2 {}  => {b}       1          1    1
# 3 {a} => {b}       1          1    1
# 4 {b} => {a}       1          1    1
```

You may need to loosen `supp` and/or `conf` to find rules in your data set.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of trouble with coercion (e.g., 'as(dataname, "transactions"..).

I believe that this is due to the fact that I have duplicate records (i.e., the same item purchased more than once in the same transation, when the data is in 'single' format).

This is what finally worked for me:

```
Transactions<- read.transactions("Data with tx ids, item names, in
                      single format.csv", 
                      rm.duplicates= TRUE, sep=",",
                      format = "single", cols = c(7,9));
```

(tx id in column 7, item names in column 9)